# saving data in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some unsolved problem right now. My game is done, now I am at the last stage. In the main menu of the game there will be  a button called goodies. Only appears when the user win the game once. I can do until that part . But the last part is to save that goodies. Meaning when the player exist the game after he able to make the button appear, the button still there when he gets back to the game? Could you guys help me out I am not quite sure how to do it. I heard a lot about NSUSerDefault, but don know how it works and how to apply it properly. Thanks for any help.

```
DegrafeurAppDelegate *appdelegate = (DegrafeurAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //BOOL b = appdelegate.checkStatus;

    if(appdelegate.checkStatus == YES)
    {
        [goodies setVisible:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [goodies setVisible:NO];
    }
```

This is my code to enable the button after winning once. But how to save it, please help me

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can user NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults myPrefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
[myPrefs setBool:YES forKey:@"displayed_win_button"];
[myPrefs release];
```

and later to check the value:

```
if([myPrefs boolForKey:@"displayed_win_button"]) { ... }
```